# Проблема с переключением класса. В чем может быть проблема?

Tags: javascript

Класс не переключается.В чем может быть проблема?

```js
const questionBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".question__btn")

questionBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  questionBtn.classList.toggle("question__btn--active")
});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/93ohxbe8/

Comment: В том что `querySelectorAll()` возвращает NodeList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно причина в том что `querySelectorAll()` возвращает `nodeList` а не элемент, если у вас 1 такой элемент то вы можете использовать `querySelector()`

```js
const questionBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".question__btn")

questionBtn.forEach((element => {
  element.addEventListener("click", () => {
    element.classList.toggle("question__btn--active")
  });
}))
```

```css
.question__btn {
  padding: 12px 24px;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}

.question__btn--active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<button class="question__btn">Press</button>
```

Comment: Cпасибо вам большое, очень помогли.